# AzureDevOps API to retrieve build results based on build id

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

We are trying to use Microsoft Azure DevOps API and retrieve following information for each build under each project in Azure DevOps organization. Ultimate goal is to retrieve these datils using C# code and use as a data to make some decisions in one of our dashboard. As we can see, these details available in the summary of the build once build completed (in Azure DevOps build summary page).

- Unit Test Status
- Code Coverage
- Build Status
- Deployment Status
- Automated Test Execution Status

We have referred [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) Microsoft official documentation in our research. And found that below GET methods has some information that may help with our research, but unfortunately these does not contains all the information that we are looking for.

- Build
- Builds
- History

Could someone help us by recommending possible candidate API's to efficiently extract this data?